# Prove that a 3-regular graph with n vertices has a number of edges divisible by 3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

This is a study questions for my final exam. I've been having some trouble proving it.

**Attempt**

Since this is a 3-regular graph, each vertex is incident to three edges. Therefore the total number of edges in the graph is $3n$ - (the number of edges that we counted twice)

This second quantity (number of edges we counted twice) is tricky. I'm having trouble calculating it. I'd appreciate some help on this question. Thank You.

Comment: Here is a clean approach: compute the cardinality of set $\ \{(v\ e)\in E\times V : v\in e\},\ $ where $E$ is the set of edges, and $V$ is the set of vertices. Compute this set of pairs in two ways: once with respect to $\ |V|,\ $ the other time with respect to $\ |E|.\ $ This leads to an equation of the form $\ f(|E|) = g(|V|).\ $ It'll be a snap to compute $\ |E|,\ $ and to see that $\ |E|\ $ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: An edge gets counted once for each vertex that is incident to it. How many vertices are incident to each edge?

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm still confused. Each edge is incident to two vertices. But how can we use that info to find out how many edges we counted twice?

Comment: Each edge is incident to two vertices, so each edge was counted exactly twice. Thus $3n$ is twice the number of edges.

Answer (score 1):

By definition:

- **Every vertex is the endpoint of exactly $3$ edges.**  Thus there are $3n$ endpoints (where $n$ is the number of vertices).

This first point seems to be what you're counting in the question (not *edges* but *endpoints*).

- **Every edge has exactly $2$ endpoints.**  Thus there are $2e$ endpoints (where $e$ is the number of edges).

Now we just put these together and use elementary number theory.